# add a shapefile layer to a specific postgis table

Tags: postgis, request

I have a question about Postgis: 
There is a way(extension) to import a shapefile and add it directly to a specific table (not database), if not there is a request to joint vertically two tables like : i have table A and table B

```
                                 Table "A"
         gid             |             Name             |        geom
-------------------------+------------------------------+-------------------
          1              | Arganier                     | xxxxxxxxxxxxxx 

                                    Table "B"
         gid             |             Name             |        geom
-------------------------+------------------------------+-------------------
          1              | Abousier                     | xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

And then i want to joint this two tables and get the following table:

```
                                 Table "A"
         gid             |             Name             |        geom
-------------------------+------------------------------+-------------------
          1              | Arganier                     | xxxxxxxxxxxxxx 
-------------------------+------------------------------+-------------------
          2              | Abousier                     | xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the shp2pgsql utility to create the required sql statements which can then be loaded into your database of choice.

```
USAGE: shp2pgsql [<options>] <shapefile> [[<schema>.]<table>]
```

See the [man page](https://man.cx/shp2pgsql) for usage.

You'll end up with something like:

```
shp2pgsql my_shapefile my_table > my_statements.sql
psql -d my_database -f my_statements.sql
```

or on a *nix system:

```
shp2pgsql my_shapefile my_table | psql -d my_database
```

You may want to alter your psql options depending on what's required to connect to your Postgres server.

If you wish to merge two different tables:

```
insert into master_table (<col1>, <col2>, <geom_col>,...)
select <col1>, <col2>, <geom_col>,... from second_table;
```

Just don't list the gid column (presumably a serial field primary key).